# Appendix and Bookmark

Tags: bookmarks, appendix

My goals are as follows:

1. Show the appendix as a section without numbering in the main text.
2. Show an item named "Appendix" in the bookmark.
3. When clicking the "Appendix" in the bookmark, it jumps to the place where the appendix is.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{preliminary}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl, amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=red,
urlcolor=blue,
linktoc=all,
citecolor=blue
       }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[letterpaper, width=17cm, height=20cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{nicematrix}



\definecolor{mygray1}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{mygray2}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{mygray3}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{mygray4}{gray}{0.2}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{claim}{{\sc Claim}}
\newtheorem{condition}{Condition}

\newcommand{\tc}{\textcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cancel}




\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[capposition=bottom]{floatrow}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\argmax}{arg\max}
\newcommand{\argmin}{arg\min}
\newcommand*{\QEDA}{\null\nobreak\hfill\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}%


\begin{document}

\title{Title\thanks{I thank }}

\author{Author\thanks{LaTeX University}}

%\affil{University of Michigan}

%\date{\today}
%\date{}
\date{April 13, 2022}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

 abstract 

\noindent {\bf Keywords}: keywords
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}

\newpage

\section{Main Body}

\newpage


\section{Conclusion}

\newpage



\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\section*{Appendix}



\end{document}
```

It achieves goals 1 and 2, but not 3.

Edit: I reversed \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
and \section*{Appendix} and it worked.

Comment: Remove the `*`.

Comment: @dexteritas But I don't want to number the appendix...

Comment: You can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}` to add it.

Comment: @dexteritas The text "Appendix" disappears when I use $\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}$

Comment: Please just make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and explain your goal in more detail. Do you want it to appear in the table of contents or only in bookmarks that are shown in some PDF-viewers?

Comment: @dexteritas Thank you for your suggestions. I made an MWE and hope this makes my goal clearer.

Comment: @dexteritas Ah, I reversed \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix} and \section*{Appendix} and it worked.